# Change button style programmatically based on a boolean value. Unselected item should return to original style

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-button

I'm creating a checklist, I have 2 buttons. When I click false, I want to change the style. When I click on true, I want the false to return to original style, and change the style of True button

```
<LinearLayout             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inspectionItemText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="Inspection Item"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/itemInspectedTrue"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:text="Pass"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/itemInspectedFalse"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:text="Fail"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use selector.

Comment: you can add button dynamically in your layout and change style attrib

Answer (score 0):

You can not change view theme programmatically (which is defined in xml), but you can change you whole activity's theme programatically.

You can use a selector to differentiate between selected and non selected state

`drawable/button_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
  <item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

and in layout xml file

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/itemInspectedFalse"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="Fail"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```